# The engineers' style of drawing an electric circuit vs. the physicists' one - a troublesome exercise

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

I tutor an automation student in physics and math. In particular we deal with all sorts of physical systems with an input $x(t)$ and an output funtion $y(t)$ where the goals is to provide a mathematical model (e.g. the equations of motion for the system) and calculate the transfer function $G(s):= \frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}$.

One type of above systems are electric circuits where the goal is to use the Kirhoff laws to obtain a transfer function where the input and output signals are two voltages.

The problem we're facing is the usage of the engineers' way of drawing electric circuits, i.e. with a common ground level and voltages expressed as horizontal lines. An example below is the one I had trouble with:

[image: Picture as drawn by the professor]

Now my understanding of this style of drawing circuits lead me to believe that this is equivalent to this:

[image: My interpretation of the original cicruit]

The outgoing signal is then the value of the voltmeter. The problem with this interpretation is the fact that the coil $L$ and the capacitor $C$ wouldn't contribute at all to the transfer function, as there would be no current going through them at all, as far as my understanding of electric circuits.

So my question is: where am I making my mistake? If it is in the way I interpret the circuit, then is there a general way to understand and analyze this "engineers'" style of circuits?

Comment: The circuit is only interesting for *AC* signals. You are right  there is no current through C and L for *DC*, when $s = 0$.

Comment: @alephzero, even for AC signals, the L and C elements won't contribute to the transfer function of the circuit given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (an electrical engineer) agree with your interpretation of the schematic.

> The problem with this interpretation is the fact that the coil L and the capacitor C wouldn't contribute at all to the transfer function,

This is true when there is no load attached to the output of the filter.

It's possible that the actual point of the exercise was to show that series components with an open circuit don't affect the circuit behavior.

But also, consider that as soon as you attach a load to the output, the inductor and capacitor will contribute to the transfer function.

One of the main results of a first circuit theory course is a systematic way (actually a whole menagerie of ways) to represent circuits so that you can predict how they will operate with any possible linear load attached. Or with the the source attached to the opposite side and the output taken from what was originally the input side.

Comment: My systems knowledge is a bit fuzzy, and I studied mechanical not electrical (so take this comment with appropriate grains of salt).  Based on the first diagram, I think expecting a load on both sides makes sense.  $u_1 (t)$ and $u_2 (t)$ look identical, so unless I'm just completely misunderstanding, I would expect a load on the right side as much as I would expect one on the left.  So this makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because it does address the main point of my question. However I don't think I understand what you mean by attaching a load to the output. Does it mean just a parallel attachment of some impedance?

Comment: @Lurco, yes, to do anything useful with a filter, it has to deliver some energy to some other circuit or subsystem. That means connecting something to the filter's output. Ideally, that load might have very high impedance (in which case you're right, the L and C have no effect, and this is a very poor filter to use in that system), but in the general case it could have any impedance you want to design it to have.